# How can I pattern match using a condition like the nth letter of a given word equals the mth letter of another word?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Given a list of words like ["hello","pale","joke","okay"], how do I convert the following statement into Haskell code?

> Give me the set(s) of words in the list such that the second letter of the first word equals the first letter of the second word.

In this case, the answer is ["joke","okay"] since the letter 'o' satisfies the condition. In general, how do I specify that I need the set of words where the nth letter of one word equals the mth letter of another.

Further, how can I extend this concept to multiple words, for eg, give me the set of words where the fourth letter of the first word equals the third letter of the second and the last letter of the first word equals the first letter of the third word. The result for the given list should be ["hello","pale","okay"].

Comment: Isn't it the 'o' that satisfies the required conditions in your example?

Comment: @bwegs Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Your problem gets rather complex in the last paragraph.  What do you have at this point?  Have you solved the original problem of just matching pairs of words?  In what ways do you think you can extend that solution to work with the nth letter matches the mth letter?  What information would you need to pass to a function for the completely general case?

Comment: @bheklilr No, I haven't solved the original problem at this point. I'm an absolute beginner who's teaching himself Haskell. However, based on what little I know, I feel that this problem will have an elegant solution in Haskell. Concretely, I was wondering whether crossword puzzles can be solved if the words that can be used for the creating the puzzle come from a fixed dictionary. So, that means the function must accept a dictionary, and how each word is linked to another word or words. I hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first use case is pretty simple to solve in Haskell, you first need to pair up consecutive words:

```
pairs :: [String] -> [(String, String)]
pairs wrds = zip wrds $ drop 1 wrds
```

Then write the logic to match the second letter of the first word with the first letter of the second word, pretty straightforward with pattern matching:

```
secondLetterMatchesFirstLetter :: String -> String -> Bool
secondLetterMatchesFirstLetter (_:a:_) (b:_) = a == b
secondLetterMatchesFirstLetter _ _ = False
```

Finally tie these together:

```
matchingWords :: [String] -> [(String, String)]
matchingWords = filter (uncurry secondLetterMatchesFirstLetter) . pairs
```

Doing this for any mth and nth letters involves a few extra arguments along with swapping out `secondLetterMatchesFirstLetter` with a more general function, lets write that first:

```
mthMatchesNth :: Int -> Int -> String -> String -> Bool
mthMatchesNth m n first second = (first `safeIdx` m) == (second `safeIdx` n)
    where
        -- Note: this isn't efficient
        safeIdx [] n = Nothing
        safeIdx (x:_) 0 = Just x
        safeIdx (_:rest) n = safeIdx rest (n - 1)

matchingWords :: Int -> Int -> [String] -> [(String, String)]
matchingWords m n = filter (uncurry $ mthMatchesNth m n) . pairs
```

Extending this to work on arbitrary groupings of words would be somewhat more complicated, and I'll let you work on that on your own.  This code should get you started for understanding how to do the matching itself, particularly since you'll be able to reuse the `mthMatchesNth` function regardless.  I would consider making a data type to represent that problem, since just passing some `Int`s around would make it hard to keep up with the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I can extend this solution. By the way, is there something wrong with my question? I don't think it's an exact duplicate because I couldn't find a solution after searching on Google. Or does the question violate any other guideline?

Comment: @GreenNoob it's probably more because you didn't show any work in your question, and it looks a lot like a homework problem. Keep in mind that stackoverflow has this ideal of being a repository of useful questions and answers, and it could be argued that your question would mainly help lazy students looking for a quick solution to their homework. Of course, SO is more than that in reality, people come here when they're stuck on a problem and they want a specific answer.

Comment: @GreenNoob  In the future, it'd be better to ask questions about how to extend code you already have to solve a more complex problem, rather than trying to get the solution to begin with. The downvotes are meant to indicate that you haven't asked a question useful to others, not that you have a duplicate or trivial problem.